# xml elements position

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0

Here is an xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<contact-information>

  <full-name>Peter John</full-name>
  <address_line_1>some place</address_line_1>
  <address_line_2>some place2</address_line_2>
  <city>some city</city>
  <state>some state</state>
  <zip>54000</zip>
  <country>some country</country>
  <phone>2121314144</phone>
  <email>abc@xyz.com</email>

</contact-information>

<professional-experience-section>
  <section-name>PROFESSIONAL EXPERIENCE</section-name>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <company>
    <name>Computer Sciences Corporation</name>
    <city>New York</city>
    <state>NY</state>
    <country>United States</country>
    <job-title>
      <title>Senior Software Engineer</title>
      <start-date>Aug 1996</start-date>
      <end-date>May 2010</end-date>
      <ongoing>false</ongoing>
      <job-description>
        <bullet-point>
          <statement>C#, Visual Basic, Asp.net</statement>
        </bullet-point>
        <bullet-point>
          <statement>Inspect completed work to ensure conformance to specifications, standards, and contract requirements.</statement>
        </bullet-point>
        <bullet-point>
          <statement>Another Work Description.</statement>
        </bullet-point>
      </job-description>
    </job-title>
  </company>
  <company>
    <name>Acme</name>
    <city>Silver Spring</city>
    <state>MD</state>
    <country>United States</country>
    <job-title>
      <title>Manager</title>
      <start-date>Jul 2010</start-date>
      <end-date>present</end-date>
      <ongoing>true</ongoing>
      <job-description>
        <bullet-point>
          <statement>Report to management regarding the finances of establishment.</statement>
        </bullet-point>
        <bullet-point>
          <statement>Prepare, examine, or analyze accounting records, financial statements, or other financial reports to assess accuracy, completeness, and conformance to reporting and procedural standards.</statement>
        </bullet-point>
        <bullet-point>
          <statement>Prepare, examine, or analyze accounting records, financial statements, or other financial reports to assess accuracy, completeness, and conformance to reporting and procedural standards.</statement>
        </bullet-point>
      </job-description>
    </job-title>

    <job-title>
      <title>Analyst</title>
      <start-date>Jul 2001</start-date>
      <end-date>Jan 2010</end-date>
      <ongoing>false</ongoing>
      <job-description>
        <bullet-point>
          <statement>Study and rehearse roles from scripts in order to interpret, learn and memorize lines, stunts, and cues as directed.</statement>
        </bullet-point>
        <bullet-point>
          <statement>Work closely with directors, other actors, and playwrights to find the interpretation most suited to the role.</statement>
        </bullet-point>
      </job-description>
    </job-title>

  </company>
</professional-experience-section>


<education-section>
  <section-name>EDUCATION</section-name>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <institution>
    <name>Allston Community College</name>
    <city>Akron</city>
    <state>MA</state>
    <country>United States</country>
    <degree>Bachelor of Art in Marketing Candidate</degree>
    <end-date>Jan 2020</end-date>
    <ongoing>true</ongoing>
    <expected-completion-date>Jan 2020</expected-completion-date>
    <completed></completed>
    <bullet-point>
      <statement>detail of what i did at the allston community college</statement>
    </bullet-point>
  </institution>
  <institution>
    <name>Boston College</name>
    <city>Boston</city>
    <state>MA</state>
    <country>United States</country>
    <degree>Bachelor of Science in Information Systems</degree>
    <end-date>Jul 1990</end-date>
    <ongoing>false</ongoing>
    <expected-completion-date></expected-completion-date>
    <completed>true</completed>
    <bullet-point>
      <statement>Lorem Ipsum</statement>
    </bullet-point>
  </institution>
  <institution>
    <name>Testing</name>
    <city>Testing</city>
    <state>PA</state>
    <country>United States</country>
    <degree>Completed coursework towards Bachelor of Art in Marketing</degree>
    <end-date>Mar 1963</end-date>
    <ongoing>false</ongoing>
    <expected-completion-date></expected-completion-date>
    <completed>false</completed>
    <bullet-point>
      <statement>Lorem Ipsum</statement>
    </bullet-point>
  </institution>
  <institution>
    <name>Testing</name>
    <city>Testing</city>
    <state>PA</state>
    <country>United States</country>
    <degree>Completed coursework towards Bachelor of Art in Marketing</degree>
    <end-date>Mar 1963</end-date>
    <ongoing>false</ongoing>
    <expected-completion-date></expected-completion-date>
    <completed>false</completed>
    <bullet-point>
      <statement>Lorem Ipsum</statement>
    </bullet-point>
  </institution>
</education-section>
<additional-skills-section>
  <section-name>ADDITIONAL SKILLS</section-name>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <layout>1 Column</layout>
  <bullet-point>
    <statement>Additional Skills 1</statement>
  </bullet-point>
   </additional-skills-section>
<custom-section>
  <section-name>PUBLICATIONS</section-name>
  <layout>2</layout>
  <bullet-point>
    <statement>test</statement>
  </bullet-point>
 </custom-section>
```

This xml file is transformed by the following xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/resume">
    <xsl:value-of select="/resume/contact-information/full-name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="/resume/contact-information/address_line_1"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="/resume/contact-information/address_line_2"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="/resume/contact-information/city"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="/resume/contact-information/state"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="/resume/contact-information/country"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="/resume/contact-information/phone"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="/resume/professional-experience-section/company"> 
        <!--for company name-->
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="city"/>, <xsl:value-of select="state"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
        <!--loop into job title-->
        <xsl:for-each select="job-title"> 
            <!--for job title-->
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/> 
            <!--for job start date and job end date-->
            <xsl:value-of select="start-date"/> – <xsl:value-of
                select="end-date"/>
            <!--Loop into job description-->
            <xsl:for-each select="job-description"> 
                <!--loop into each bullet point-->
                <xsl:for-each select="bullet-point">
                    <xsl:value-of select="statement"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>


    <!--education section-->
    <!--for education section's section name-->
    <xsl:value-of select="/resume/education-section/section-name"/>
    <!--loop into each institution name-->
    <xsl:for-each select="/resume/education-section/institution"> 
        <!--for institution name  -->
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <!--for institution city and state-->
        <xsl:value-of select="city"/>, <xsl:value-of select="state"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
        <!--for degree of a particular institution-->
        <xsl:value-of select="degree"/>-<xsl:value-of select="expected-completion-date"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="bullet-point">
            <xsl:for-each select="statement" >
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>


</xsl:template>
```

The professional section will always be rendered ahead of the educational section. I want to develop a mechanism that sections can be changed in xsl for instance if i want the information of educational section to be shown first instead of professional by using some kind of input and i don't have to do it manually. How shall i change the xml or xsl file so that i can change the order of each section at runtime in the xsl listed above?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a quick and completely parameterized solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="pOrder" select="concat('contact-information|',
                                            'professional-experience-section|',
                                            'education-section')"/>
    <xsl:template match="institution/completed|
                         institution/end-date|
                         institution/ongoing|
                         education-section/enable|
                         professional-experience-section
                            /*[not(self::company)]|
                         custom-section|
                         additional-skills-section|
                         contact-information/zip|
                         contact-information/email|
                         job-title/ongoing" priority="1"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'&#xa;')"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="resume">
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="string-length(
                                 substring-before($pOrder,
                                                  name()))"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="institution/city|company/city">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,',')"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="job-title/start-date">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' - ')"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="institution/degree">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'-')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this properly well formed input (`resume` root element), output:

```
Peter John
some place
some place2
some city
some state
some country
2121314144
Computer Sciences Corporation
New York,NY
United States
Senior Software Engineer
Aug 1996 - May 2010
C#, Visual Basic, Asp.net
Inspect completed work to ensure conformance to specifications, standards, and contract requirements.
Another Work Description.
Acme
Silver Spring,MD
United States
Manager
Jul 2010 - present
Report to management regarding the finances of establishment.
Prepare, examine, or analyze accounting records, financial statements, or other financial reports to assess accuracy, completeness, and conformance to reporting and procedural standards.
Prepare, examine, or analyze accounting records, financial statements, or other financial reports to assess accuracy, completeness, and conformance to reporting and procedural standards.
Analyst
Jul 2001 - Jan 2010
Study and rehearse roles from scripts in order to interpret, learn and memorize lines, stunts, and cues as directed.
Work closely with directors, other actors, and playwrights to find the interpretation most suited to the role.
EDUCATION
true
Allston Community College
Akron,MA
United States
Bachelor of Art in Marketing Candidate-Jan 2020
detail of what i did at the allston community college
Boston College
Boston,MA
United States
Bachelor of Science in Information Systems-Lorem Ipsum
Testing
Testing,PA
United States
Completed coursework towards Bachelor of Art in Marketing-Lorem Ipsum
Testing
Testing,PA
United States
Completed coursework towards Bachelor of Art in Marketing-Lorem Ipsum
```

**Note**: `$pOrder` param is a sequence with a relative order to process `resume` children.

Answer (score 0):

Have two separate xsl stylesheets; one as above, and the other with the

```
<xsl:value-of select="/resume/education-section/section-name"/>
```

loop ahead of the professional experience loop.

At run time, decide which stylesheet you wish to invoke.

This really is not meant to be a smart-aleck answer, I honestly think this is the best way to achieve what the questioner wants

Comment: I also thought of this to have multiple stylesheets but suppose if i have more than 2 sections how many combinations will i have to make?

Answer (score 0):

**The following transformation uses an external parameter (and can easily be adjusted to read from another document) the desired sections and their desired order**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:param name="pRanks">
  <section name="contact-information" r="1"/>
  <section name="professional-experience-section" r="2"/>
  <section name="education-section" r="3"/>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:variable name="vRanks" select=
     "document('')/*/xsl:param[@name='pRanks']"/>

 <xsl:template match="/resume">

   <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name()=$vRanks/*/@name]">
   <xsl:sort select="$vRanks/*[@name=name(current())]/@r"
             data-type="number"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="contact-information">
    <xsl:value-of select="full-name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="address_line_1"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="address_line_2"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="city"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="state"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="phone"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="company">
  <!--for company name-->
  <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="city"/>, <xsl:value-of select="state"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
  <!--loop into job title-->
  <xsl:for-each select="job-title">
    <!--for job title-->
    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
      <!--for job start date and job end date-->
      <xsl:value-of select="start-date"/> – <xsl:value-of
           select="end-date"/>
       <!--Loop into job description-->
       <xsl:for-each select="job-description">
          <!--loop into each bullet point-->
          <xsl:for-each select="bullet-point">
            <xsl:value-of select="statement"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="institution">
  <!--for institution name  -->
  <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
  <!--for institution city and state-->
  <xsl:value-of select="city"/>, <xsl:value-of select="state"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
  <!--for degree of a particular institution-->
  <xsl:value-of select="degree"/>-<xsl:value-of select="expected-completion-date"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="bullet-point">
    <xsl:for-each select="statement" >
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="education-section">
    <!--education section-->
    <!--for education section's section name-->
    <xsl:value-of select="section-name"/>
    <!--loop into each institution name-->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="institution"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do note**:

I haven't corrected any of the specific processing that was provided -- just grouped it into templates and provided the ordering mechanism. It is up to the OP (original poster) to decide how to finalize the presentation.

In particular, most of the code can still be refined by grouping it into templates, which will allow decoupling the code, simplifying it and dectreasing the dependencies and hard-coded information.